# Load specific properties in LoadQuery

Tags: csom

The following code will return an IEnumerable containing the particular content type object in which I am interested.

```
string contentTypeName;
IEnumerable<ContentType> existingContentTypes =
    site.Context.LoadQuery<ContentType>(contentTypes.Where(
       x => x.Name == contentTypeName)
);
```

However, the content type object will have all properties loaded. Is there a way to make the query load only the particular fields of interest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
//string contentTypeName = "Item";

IEnumerable<ContentType> existingContentTypes = site.Context.LoadQuery(
     contentTypes.Where(x => x.Name == contentTypeName).Include(
         ct => ct.Id,
         ct => ct.Name,
         ct => ct.Description,
         ct => ct.Group
     )
);
```